# Configure OkHttp on Android to trust both content in "AndroidCAStore" and also explicit certificates

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

**My setup:**

- OkHttp 4.2.2
- Conscrypt-android 2.0.0

I'm trying to configure OkHttp to accept:

1. Built-in commercial server certificates (signed by CAs included in `AndroidCAStore`)

   - Internally Conscrypt will then return KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore")
2. Non-commercial server certificates (signed by a bundled CA certificate in my app)

I have made both solutions work separately:

- To solve (1) I just initialize the trust manager factory with a null key store.
- To solve (2) I initialize the trust manager factory using an initialized key store with the bundled CA.

**How do I solve both at the same time?** I.e. how do i I get a copy of AndroidCAStore and add my certificates to it and use that to initialize the trust manager factory?

Comment: Normally certificates with OkHttp can be handled with the class HandshakeCertificates.Builder (package okhttp3.tls). You can add multiple trusted certificates from different KeyStores. The HandshakeCertificates class has the method trustManager() for create the TrustManagerFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (exception handling ommitted):

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(null);

// Ommitted: Code to add certificates explictly from file

final KeyStore androidCAStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
androidCAStore.load(null);
final Enumeration<String> androidCAStoreAliases = androidCAStore.aliases();
while (androidCAStoreAliases.hasMoreElements()) {
     final String param = androidCAStoreAliases.nextElement();
     keyStore.setEntry(param, androidCAStore.getEntry(param, null), null);
}
```